# Manipular datos en DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data

Dado este dataframe:

```
   user_id   device_id  game_version
-----------------------------------------
1   user1   device_id2  2.0 
2   user1   device_id3  2.0 
7   user2   device_id4  1.0 
10  user2   device_id5  1.0 
11  user3   device_id6  2.0 
12  user3   device_id7  1.0
```

Se quieren quitar los usuarios los cuales tienen al menos 1 **device** con `game_version = 2.0`, es decir:

- El `user3` debería eliminarse puesto que tiene un dispositivo con `game_version = 2.0`
- El `user2` debería quedar en el **df_resultante**, porque `no` presenta dispositivos con `game_version = 2.0`
- El `user1` debería eliminarse puesto que tiene dispositivos con `game_version != 1.0`

El dataframe resultante (**df_resultante**) quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
   user_id   device_id  game_version
-----------------------------------------
7   user2   device_id4  1.0 
10  user2   device_id5  1.0
```

Comment: user2 no lo eliminas aunque  se cumple la premisa "quitar los usuarios los cuales tienen **al menos 1** device con game_version = 1.0". Afirmas que no se elimina porque no tiene ninguno con versión 2.0... En cambio eliminas a user3 que no tiene ninguno con versión 1.0. Entonces, ¿lo que buscas es eliminar aquellos que tienen **al menos un dispositivo con versión diferente a 1.0**? (en el momento que un usuario tiene un  dispositivo con versión diferente a 1.0, aunque tenga otros dispositivos con versión 1.0 se eliminaría) No se si ha sido un typo, y debe ser "1 device con game_version != 1.0"

Comment: Exacto! Quiero **eliminar** aquellos usuarios que **tienen al menos un dispositivo con versión diferente a 1.0**. 
Gracias por ver el error, lo acabo de corregir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agrupar por `user_id` y luego filtrar para quedarte solo con aquellos en los que todas sus `game_version` es 1.0:

```
df.groupby("user_id").filter(lambda group: (group["game_version"] == 1.0).all())
```

o también, invirtiendo la lógica, filtrar aquellos que no tienen ninguna  versión diferente a 1.0:

```
df.groupby("user_id").filter(lambda group: ~(group["game_version"] != 1.0).any())
```

---

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data = io.StringIO("""\
user_id   device_id  game_version
user1   device_id2  2.0 
user1   device_id3  2.0 
user2   device_id4  1.0 
user2   device_id5  1.0 
user3   device_id6  2.0 
user3   device_id7  1.0 
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+", engine="python")
df.index = [1, 2, 7, 10, 11, 12]
only_1.0 = (df.groupby("user_id")
              .filter(lambda group: ~(group["game_version"] != 1.0
              ).any())
              )
```

> ```
> >>> only_v1
>
>    user_id   device_id  game_version
> 7    user2  device_id4           1.0
> 10   user2  device_id5           1.0
> ```

Comment: Perfecto, me ayudó bastante!